# variable holding style value can't be changed

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, position, styles

I am curious about a simple problem. Here is the code:

```js
var square = document.getElementById('square')
var left = square.style.left

function moveNoVariable() {
  square.style.left = "100px" // works
}

function moveWithVariable() {
  left = "100px" // doesn't work
}

moveNoVariable()
```

```css
#square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
```

I am just wondering why the style won't change if I use "left" even though it is storing the correct value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

square.style.left is a string. If you put a string into a variable, the variable will store a copy of the given string. If you put an object into a variable, the variable will refer to the original object. So you could do this for example:

```
var square = document.getElementById('square')
var style = square.style

function moveNoVariable() {
  square.style.left = "100px" // works
}

function moveWithVariable() {
  style.left = "100px" // will work
}
```

Comment: This.  This is the answer.  I'm deleting mine because it's just confusing.

Comment: Perfect, understand it now.